# How to use for loop to extract rows with similar elements across 2 dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, one is a Free Trade Agreement dataset that contains many columns, the columns c1 to c91 denote different countries part of a particular Free Trade Agreement, as shown below:
[FTA data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeQ89.png)

FTA data e.g.

```
No   Base_treaty   entry_type               c1          c2            c3
1     1            treaty             Afghanistan     India           NA
2     2            treaty                Algeria      Egypt          Ghana
3     3            treaty                Algeria      Angola         Benin
4     4            treaty                Egypt        Jordan         Morocco
5     5            treaty                Albania      Bulgaria         NA
6     6            treaty                Albania      Croatia          NA
```

The other data frame contains trade data between two particular countries, i and j. [Trade Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqrSv.png)

```
   inventor_ctry_i   authority_ctry_j           
1    Albania            Bulgaria         
2    Albania            Croatia          
3    Algeria             Angola        
4    Algeria            Belgium         
5    Algeria            France          
6    Andorra            Turkey          
7    Andorra          United States   
8    Anguilla           Germany         
9    Anguilla         Switzerland     
10    Anguilla        United States
```

Desired output:

```
No   Base_treaty   entry_type         matched ctry1   matched ctry2       
 3     3            treaty                Algeria      Angola         
 5     5            treaty                Albania      Bulgaria         
 6     6            treaty                Albania      Croatia
```

I want to be able to find countries i and j in trade data that show up in the same row somewhere in between c1 to c91 of the FTA data. **If both are present in a particular row, extract the 2 countries from the row in FTA, keeping no, base treaty and entry type column intact.**

What I have done so far:

FTA_final: FTA Data, unique_pairs: Trade Data

```
specialnames <- setdiff(names(FTA_final), c("number", "base_treaty", 
"entry_type")) **#getting rid of irrelevant columns**


 table <- data.frame()` **#create empty dataframe**

 for(i in nrow(FTA_final)){`
  for(j in seq_along(specialnames)){`
    for(p in nrow(unique_pairs)){`
        if (FTA_final[i,j] %in% unique_pairs[p,])`
          {table <- rbind(table,FTA_final[i,c(1:3, j)])}`
   ` }`
  `}`
`}`  **#for loop**
```

Nothing happens when I run these codes, not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may not really need `for` loop at all. If you provide a reproducible example and expected results, you may have a good chance to get an answer.

Comment: Would you be able to format your question using the code block format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Ronak Shah for your suggestions

As suggested by @Ronak Shah, I was able to get the relevant rows that had countries i and j in them:

```
cols <- paste0('c', 1:3)
all_countries <- do.call(paste, Trade_data)


output<- FTA_data[rowSums(sapply(all_countries, function(x) 
      apply(FTA_data[cols], 1, function(y) 
            grepl(x, paste(y, collapse = " "))))) > 0, ]
```

Afterwhich, I did this:

```
 do.call(rbind, combn(grep("^c\\d+$", names(output)), 2, function(x) 
 cbind(output[1:3], setNames(output[x], paste0("c", 1:2))), simplify=F))
```

This helps me get all possible combinations across "c" columns, while retaining columns 1:3, i.e. No, Base Entry and entry_type.

After this, a simple left join with trade data will gave me the desired i and j pairs and the output:

```
No   Base_treaty   entry_type         matched ctry1   matched ctry2       
3     3            treaty                Algeria        Angola         
5     5            treaty                Albania       Bulgaria         
6     6            treaty                Albania       Croatia
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to row-wise `paste` the value of `Trade_data` to get combinations of countries that trade together. We can then create a combination of countries in `FTA_data` and check if any of the combination matches `all_countries`.

```
cols <- paste0('c', 1:3)
all_countries <- do.call(paste, Trade_data)

data <- apply(FTA_data[cols], 1, function(x) {
           x <- na.omit(x)
           if(length(x) <= 1) return(NULL)
           temp <- combn(x, 2)
           inds <- combn(x, 2, paste, collapse = " ") %in% all_countries
           if(any(inds)) temp[, inds]
})

new_data <- FTA_data[!sapply(data, is.null), ]
new_data[cols] <- NULL

final_data <- cbind(new_data, do.call(rbind, data))
final_data

#  No Base_treaty entry_type       1        2
#3  3           3     treaty Algeria   Angola
#5  5           5     treaty Albania Bulgaria
#6  6           6     treaty Albania  Croatia
```

---

Here is another way :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

output<- FTA_data[rowSums(sapply(all_countries, function(x) 
          apply(FTA_data[cols], 1, function(y) 
                grepl(x, paste(y, collapse = " "))))) > 0, ]



output %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('c'), 
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
 filter(value %in% Trade_data$inventor_ctry_i | 
        value %in% Trade_data$authority_ctry_j) %>%
 group_by(No, Base_treaty, entry_type) %>%
 mutate(name = paste0('c', row_number())) %>%
 pivot_wider()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I shall try it out

Comment: I am getting an error, "invalid regular expression, reason 'Out of memory'"

Comment: Thank you so much! It definitely works in extracting the relevant rows. Is there any way to drop the 3rd country that does not match i and j? Because my actual data has c1 all the way to c91, ideally it would be better to only extract matching pairs

Comment: I am thinking along the lines of doing a for loop on the "output" table to get the 2 countries that match. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @TanviJohri Check updated answer. Maybe this is way too convoluted but seems to work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ran the code, and got the following error; Perhaps because my actual number of "c" columns are 91? 

"Error in combn(na.omit(x), 2) : n < m "

Comment: I think there are certain cases where there is only 1 non-NA value or 0. I updated the answer to handle that case.

Comment: The codes work, but cbinding the new data to data creates some problems. The number of columns do not match. "Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 17)"

Comment: I am not sure about this error. Check the length of the dataframe and list returned from `apply`.

Comment: They are different, I am not sure why. FTA: 1178 obs, Data list: 1178, new_data: 509 obs. I think the Data list did not filter out pair wise combis? When I viewed data list, some elements had 2x6 / 2x20 characters

Comment: I included "if(length(x) <= 1 | length(x)>2) return(NULL)" for the code in data, which worked. But I am not sure if it is correct/makes sense

Comment: `if(length(x) <= 1 | length(x)>2)` covers all the cases. It will always be `TRUE`.

Comment: Hmm is there any way to proceed from `output<- FTA[rowSums(sapply(all_countries, function(x) apply(FTA[cols], 1, function(y) grepl(x, paste(y, collapse = " "))))) > 0, ]` instead? Using for loops perhaps?

Comment: That code gives the rows in which we find a match but you also need the specific countries as well.

Comment: I hardly use `for` loops in R. There are better ways to loop. I have updated the answer using another approach. See if that helps.

Comment: I tried pivot longer but it does not drop to the 2 specific countries  :(  
I shall try to search on permutation functions to see if it helps

Comment: As an add on to @Ronak Shah, after doing this: 

   `output<- FTA_data[rowSums(sapply(all_countries, function(x) 
          apply(FTA_data[cols], 1, function(y) 
                grepl(x, paste(y, collapse = " "))))) > 0, ]`


I did this: 


    `df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(cols), function(i) t(combn(output[i,4:6],2))))`

This gives all possible pairwise combinations across "c" columns, but I am not sure how to do this while retaining No, Base Entry and entry_type, as those columns are important for my project. I can then get unique pairs by matching with trade data.